# generating diagrammatic or hierarchical structure of game code

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to have a diagrammatic or hierarchical look of my Cocos2d game structure (especially classes and methods). Is the any open source software that can generate this from my code? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can do this (at least with C and C++ code) when you have [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) installed.